# How to Remove PFUser Current User from List Total User?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, parse-platform

i'm using Parse.com I wanted to ask you something if you can ... How do I delete from the list the total number of users CurrentUser? I would avoid that the report will also be made with oneself: D Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect Guys .. then I found the method ... In layman's terms to exclude the PFUser Current User from a query to show only the App users but not the CurrentUser is just the use of notEqualTo in the query but it should be associated with the string that we want to remove from the query

I hope this can help other people :)
Do not pay too much attention to the constants: D

```
PFQuery * query = [self.RelazioniUtenti query];
[query whereKey: FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME notEqualTo: [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey: FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME]];
[query orderByAscending: FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^ (NSArray * objects, NSError * error) {
```